# How to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{s}\ln(s)ds$ and show that this is equal to $(-\gamma+i\pi)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, number-theory

I discovered this very interesting integral: $$\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{s}\ln(s)ds$$ which is related to another form of my earlier work with the function $f(x)=\frac{x^{s-1}}{s^{x}-1}$ so how is this interesting was that this integral is said to “diverged” but by some numerical calculation this approximate a finite value $(≈-\gamma+i\pi)$ how in the world this has something to do with $\pi$ and the Euler’s Mascheroni constant and $i$?

I was intrigued but I don’t know a way to show that this is indeed equivalent or perhaps *approximate*:$$\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{s}\ln(s)ds≈
-\gamma+i\pi$$

What I have tried so far, does not getting me anywhere I tried to use the **Dominated Convergence Theorem (DCT)** for $e^{s}$ but I’m not familiar with the concept so I am not able to apply it properly, the binomial expression also giving me a lot of trouble after expressing it in the form of *(DCT)* and making some substitutions

And if somehow someone can explain how is this related to $\pi$ and Euler-constant it would be much more appreciated thank you!

Comment: Which branch of logarithm are you using?

Comment: Which branch do you mean?

Comment: How do you define $\ln s$ for negative $s$?

Comment: Assuming $s>0$ then we have $\ln(s)+i\pi=\ln(-s)$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the principal branch of $\ln$,
\begin{align*}
\int_{ - \infty }^0 {e^s \ln (s)ds} & = \int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - t} \ln ( - t)dt}  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - t} \ln (t)dt}  + \int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - t} \pi idt}  \\ &= \left[ {\frac{d}{{dx}}\int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - t} t^{x - 1} dt} } \right]_{x = 1}  + \int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - t} \pi idt} = \Gamma '(1) + \pi i =  - \gamma  + \pi i.
\end{align*}

Comment: That’s a pretty neat trick! I assumed that the function diverged based on the look of the graph, I didn’t know you could use the integrand to re-express the function, will this trick also works generally for other integrals?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "function"? Do you know about improper integrals, integrable singularities, etc.?

Comment: I know pretty much about functions and single-variable calculus what I don’t know are concepts depth in real analysis like principle branch within complex and real analysis, integrable singularities etc. I’m still learning and developing my concepts within these subjects that’s why this site is such a great help for self-studying

Comment: Your problem was mainly the integrability of $\ln$ near $0$ I assume. $\ln$ "blows up" at the origin but its integral from $0$ to $1$, say, is still finite: $$
\int_0^1 {\ln x\,dx}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\varepsilon  \to 0 + } \int_\varepsilon ^1 {\ln x\,dx}  =  - 1 - \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\varepsilon  \to 0 + } (\varepsilon \ln \varepsilon  - \varepsilon ) =  - 1 - (0 - 0) =  - 1.
$$